# Subtree push in JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am writing a little app using JGit and ran into a problem. It seems the JGit docs are very limited, and doesn't give much suggestion for where to go for plumbing tasks. (http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide)

What is the JGit version of `git subtree push --prefix folder upstream branch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. `git-subtree` is a git extension build on top of standard commands.

However you can try to rewrite [`cmd_push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.9.3/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh#L742) logic in java by using [`org.eclipse.jgit.api.GitCommand`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/GitCommand.html) implementations.